# Discord.js v12+ Changing channel name error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I cant seem to figure out why this doesn't work to edit the channel name for the member count...Can someone explain to me how this is wrong and what I can do to fix it?

```
    bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].join_role) {
        var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === botconfig["join_roles"].role);
        if (!role) return console.log("role not found (Config: 'role')");
        member.addRole(role);
    }
    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].welcome_leave_channel) {
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["channel_setup"].welcome_channel);
        if (!channel) return console.log("join channel not found (Config: 'welcome_channel')");
        channel.send(`${member} (${member.user.tag}) has joined **Overlord**`, { files: ['1.png'] }).then(async message => {
        await message.react("")
      })
    }
    // Member count channel update
    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].member_count_channel) {
        member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).channel.edit({ name: `⇝︱Member Count ${member.guild.memberCount}`}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
    }
});

// Leave Message
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].welcome_leave_channel) {
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["channel_setup"].welcome_channel);
        if (!channel) return console.log("leave channel not found (Config: 'welcome_channel')");
    }
    // Member count channel update
    if(botconfig["module_toggles"].member_count_channel) {
        member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).channel.edit({ name: `⇝︱Member Count ${member.guild.memberCount}`}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

This error is with this line

```
member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).channel.edit({ name: `⇝︱Member Count ${member.guild.memberCount}`}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

There are 2 of these lines. Some of the rest of this code has nothing to do with it but it tells me that `.edit` Is not a function even though in the docs it says that is how you change a channel name...

Comment: @ceqoX answer is good, I just wanted to point out that your code isn't working because you're trying to access `channel` property of a Channel. In fact, you had to only type `.edit()` and not `.channel.edit()` because the result returned by the `.find()` method is already a Channel object :)

Comment: @Draityalan Actually that doesn't work either. The `.setName` doesn't work and `.edit` Doesn't work....

Comment: That's strange, does your ID is effectively a string? Maybe you can check the content for the cache collection by console.log it to see if the channel is indeed in the cache.. By the way you should use `.get("ID")` instead of `.find()` if you search by ID only.

Comment: @Draityalan Can you give me an Example of that?? Would it be like: 

`member.guild.channels.cache.get("ID" => channel.id === botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).edit({ name: `⇝︱member-count-${member.guild.memberCount}`}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);` ? because I use the config to set the ID...

Comment: What do you get if you console.log the channel?

Comment: @MrMythical `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Overlord\OverlordBot\index.js:139
        member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).edit({ name: `⇝︱member-count-${member.guild.memberCount}`}).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
                                                                                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined`

Comment: @cylence just put your var like that : `member.guild.channels.cache.get(botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel).edit(...)`.

Comment: @Draityalan Did that but still telling me this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined`

Comment: That means your channel is undefined. Make sure it exists

Comment: Or that your var `botconfig["member_count_module"].member_count_channel` may not return the string you expect, else I don't see why it don't work.. :/

Comment: @MrMythical so does that mean it should be `.channel` instead of `.channels`? or `message.member.channel.guild.channels.cache.get`?

Comment: @Draityalan Its not returning a false string. This has never broken like this on any other code. I know for sure its not a false string